# cron @reboot doing nothing

Tags: linux-mint, cron, reboot

Running `Mint 18.1 Serena`, but I am `ssh`ing into the box vs. using the gui.  I've tried everything.  Here's my cron entry:

`@reboot sleep 60;/bin/sh /home/test/Applications/scripts/startup.sh`

This is in user `test`'s `crontab -l`.

folder permissions:

```
File: 'scripts/'
Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 821h/2081d      Inode: 58843171    Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/    test)   Gid: ( 1000/    test)
Access: 2017-03-31 16:32:42.771206606 -0700
Modify: 2017-03-31 16:31:19.322038792 -0700
Change: 2017-03-31 16:31:19.322038792 -0700
Birth: -
```

`startup.sh` permissions:

```
File: 'startup.sh'
Size: 432             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 821h/2081d      Inode: 58726626    Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/    test)   Gid: ( 1000/    test)
Access: 2017-03-31 16:32:25.178476590 -0700
Modify: 2017-03-31 16:31:19.306039143 -0700
Change: 2017-03-31 16:31:19.306039143 -0700
Birth: -
```

and the contents of `startup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
kill $(cat /home/test/Applications/test1/pycpoint.pid)
cd /home/test/Applications/test1
sh test1 
cd ~

screen -d -m test2 runserver 192.168.86.110:8008
```

Not sure what I've done wrong or why this isn't working.  Also tried adding it to `init.d/` and have created `startup.service` and tried it that way.  No dice, ever.  Script works if I execute it from the command line.

`cron` reports this from `grep cron /var/log/syslog`:

```
Mar 31 17:51:16 htpc systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Mar 31 17:51:16 htpc anacron[889]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2017-03-31
Mar 31 17:51:16 htpc anacron[889]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Mar 31 17:51:16 htpc cron[909]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Mar 31 17:51:16 htpc cron[909]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
```

Help?

Comment: Make sure you have local email set up and check the user's mailbox. Cron sends you a mail with the command's output, including error messages.

Comment: can it do it locally?  and how?

Comment: Cron and other system tasks send email using whatever email server is installed on the machine. This doesn't require a network connection since it's calling the email server locally. Many distributions including Mint unhelpfully omit an email server from their default installation, you should include one. [The answers in this thread may help](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2261/how-are-administrators-supposed-to-read-roots-mail).